# How can I start a process on Windows 8.1 remotely from Linux

Tags: linux, remote-access, windows-8.1

I tried winexe - it worked fine for Windows XP and Windows 7
But it doesn't work for Windows 8.1. All I get is

```
ERROR: Cannot open control pipe - NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

The same command runs fine on older versions of Windows.
As I understand, it is because Windows 8.1 dropped support for SMB 1.0, which is used by winexe. Is there some way to force winexe to use SMB 2?

Or maybe there is some other tool that would work with Windows 8.1?

I did try PsExec (which does support SMB2, hence Windows 8.1) under wine, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Should be run as a script?

Comment: @David What do you mean?

Comment: Telnet is a possible solution

Comment: Actually, I tried it already, and so far it seems to work OK

Comment: Well, it's been some time now... In the end I stuck with Telnet. I'm just hoping that this solution will still work with win9 and I won't need a new adapter. Not a fan of Microsoft's constantly changing interfaces and standards...

Answer (score 1):

I have some cron tab tasks that needed to execute some powershell on Windows. Difficult (maybe not impossible?) to do this with the built-in Windows components.

I settled on using [Powershell Server](http://www.powershellserver.com/overview/ssh/) for that but any Windows SSH server software should work.

Comment: My next suggestion would have been this one :)

Answer (score -1):

You do it with winexe the look at winexe.

The page says it is capable of of running command on Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 systems from GNU/Linux (and possibly also from other Unices capable of building the Samba 4 software package).

I can also tell you that after configuring the windows firewall properly it also works on Windows 7 and Windows server 2008.

Comment: Please read the question carefully: winexe does work only up to Win7 (and corresponding server versions), but I'm looking for a solution that would work with Win 8.1